# How can I run Docker Sql Server on Windows Server 2019 running Docker EE

Tags: docker

I run the below docker command but for the life in me I can't get it to start and no one has an answer online.

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=<password>' -e "MSSQL_MEMORY_LIMIT_MB=3072" -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 --rm -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

I get the error

```
sqlservr: This program requires a machine with at least 2000 megabytes of memory.
```

Comment: @jannis adding --memory argument doesn't work.

Comment: You might try setting the memory for the VM with [Set-VMMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/set-vmmemory?view=win10-ps). Other than that I guess you'll need to [contact the support](https://success.docker.com/support) as Docker EE indeed is very poorly documented (at least publicly).

Comment: You could also post a ticket [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues). Searching through the tickets might also be an option. [Here's](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/293) something that seems similar, but it's not about EE.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 2019 - Host OS - Docker

Have to create Container - MSSQL 2019 Standard or Enterprise Edition.

The above is scenario is not possible and it is not supported environment. More information about the supportability for SQL Server 2019

Article for Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4047326/support-policy-for-microsoft-sql-server

Answer (score -2):

I asked Microsoft and they said this is not supported. They are supporting SQL Server 2019 for Linux and Kubernetes, instead.